# JAVA - How to convert object to list

Tags: java, list, object

I have method that is setting variable as an object

`Object value = response.getBody().jsonPath.get(variable)`

returned object is in the following format

`[{text1=value1, text2=value2, text3=value3}, {text1=value4, text2=value5, text3=value6}]`

I need somehow to itter over this end verify all values (value1-6). How can I do that?

Comment: What's preventing you from calling toString() and parsing out the values?

Comment: HI @vb381, Can you please mark the answer as accepted if you satisfied my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**MyClass.java**

```java
public class MyClass {
    private String text1;
    private String text2;

    public MyClass() {
    }

    public MyClass(String text1, String text2) {
        this.text1 = text1;
        this.text2 = text2;
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return this.text1;
    }

    public void setText1(String text1) {
        this.text1 = text1;
    }

    public String getText2() {
        return this.text2;
    }

    public void setText1(String text2) {
        this.text2 = text2;
    }
}
```

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String jsonInput = response.getBody();
List<MyClass> myObjects = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>(){});
```

**Explanation of How ObjectMapper works:**

The Jackson ObjectMapper class is the simplest way to parse JSON with Jackson. The Jackson Object mapper can parse JSON into objects of classes developed by you, or into objects of the built-in JSON tree model.
The reason it is called ObjectMapper is that it maps JSON into Java Objects (deserialization), or Java Objects into JSON (serialization).

Comment: It's a great idea to construct an object from the values and put them into a list, but can you please edit your answer to include an explanation about why this solution works.

Comment: @sorifiend Added explaination